# Convert Payload with multiple Arrays into a single Array

Tags: mule, transformation, dataweave

I have a payload that I'm trying to flatten but haven't had much luck. The payload looks like:

```
    {payload=
        [xyz,
        [{creation: 1501535135,
          id: reference_1},
         {creation: 225351535,
          id: reference_2 }]
        abc,
        [{creation: 129495124,
          id: reference_3},
         {creation: 151352244,
          id: reference_4 }]
        [{creation: 1501535135,
          id: reference_1},
         {creation: 225351535,
          id: reference }]
        [{creation: 1501535135,
          id: reference_3},
         {creation: 225351535,
          id: reference_4}]
        ]
     }
```

The output I would like in the end is a single array with all the creation and id values, so something like:

```
    {payload=
        [{creation: 1501535135,
          id: reference_1},
         {creation: 225351535,
          id: reference_2,
          {creation: 1501535135,
          id: reference_3},
         {creation: 225351535,
          id: reference_4}]
     }
```

I tried a few different things, firstly I tried to transform it by filtering only one object type of array so that the strings (xyz, abc) get dropped:

`singleArray: payload filter ((element, index) -> typeOf(element) == "array")`

At which point I was going to flatten the payload. However, the filter was throwing an error.

Comment: Please don't use this mechanism to compare types rather user `typeOf(element) is Array`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm still getting the error "There is no variable named 'typeOf'"

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are getting an error when using `typeOf`, but an alternative method is to use `is` as machaval had mentioned:

*NOTE: below examples using DW 2.0 syntax*

```
singleArray: payload filter ((element, index) -> (element is Array)
```

or this as a shorthand

```
singleArray: payload[?($ is Array)]
```

So to get your expected result I would use this:

```
singleArray: flatten(payload[?($ is Array)])
```

If you find you still need `typeOf` this *should* work (again not sure why you're seeing that error)

```
singleArray: payload filter ((element, index) -> (typeOf(element) as String) == "Array")
```

`typeOf` returns the `Type` type not the `String` type so it has to be converted to compare to a string

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I was getting an error for utilizing typeOf but I switched to this notation which worked.

`singleArray: flatten (payload filter $ is :array)`

Thanks @short stack stevens for your response you helped nudge me in the right direction.